# Has \textsubscript become a standard LaTeX command?

Tags: subscripts

TeX Live comes with a helpful fragment package, `subscript`, the copyright notice of which runs as follows:

```
% Copyright 1999 Robin Fairbairns
%
% this fragment is distributed under the conditions of the LaTeX
% Project Public Licence -- see lppl.txt in the LaTeX distribution
%
% this fragment provides a command \textsubscript, which is
% shamelessly copied from the command \textsuperscript that's part of
% LaTeX
%
% the fragment may be used as a package in its own right, if so
% needed.
```

I may be wrong but LaTeX used not to have a `\textsubscript` analogous to standard `\textsuperscript`. But now the following document compiles under `pdftex` from TeX Live 2016:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x\textsubscript{1}
\end{document}
```

However, upon compilation, the log file doesn't mention the `subscript` package. Nor does `pdftex` complain if `\usepackage{subscript}`, but, strangely enough, it *does* complain if `\newcommand\textsubscript[1]{}`. What is going on here? Has `\textsubscript` become a standard LaTeX command?  Can I just stop requesting `subscript` from now on?

Comment: IIRC `\textsubscript` has been added (along with other stuff previously covered by the `fixltx2e` package) to the kernel in the 2015/01/01 release.

Comment: The `\textsubscript` command had been added to `fixltx2e` in 2005.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\textsubscript` command was for many years part of `fixltx2e`: code which the team felt *should* be in the kernel but for various reasons did not want to add. At the start of 2015, there was a [policy change](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews22.pdf) and the contents of `fixltx2e` were 'folded' into the kernel. (There is a mechanism to back this out if required.) As a result, any recent LaTeX provides `\textsubscript`.